# Button behind the frame

Tags: python, button, tkinter, frame

I'm pretty much a complete beginner when it comes to coding. I have been using python and the tkinter GUI to code a booking system. Eventually the database will need to be integrated but I'm trying to set up the GUI first. My code is a little messy but I'm not worried about that at the minute. 
I'm try to get a button infront of the frame but it stays behind, any way of stopping this?

[image: GUI]

Here's my code for this...

```
def home_button():
    home_title = Button(book, text='HOME', background='#DEEBF7', activebackground='#DEEBF7', width=15, border=0, font = ("Helvetica 15 italic"))
    home_title.place(x=423, y=81)

def bookings_button():
    bookings_title = Label(book, text='BOOKINGS', background='#DEEBF7', font = ("Helvetica 15 italic"))
bookings_title.place(x=475, y=85)
new_booking = Button(book, text='NEW BOOKING', width=20, height=2, background='#87B7E2')
new_booking.place(x=160, y=170)

def students_button():
    students_title = Label(book, text='STUDENTS', background='#DEEBF7', font = ("Helvetica 15 italic"))
    students_title.place(x=475, y=85)

##       GUI        ####
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
#create the root window
book = Frame(root)
book.grid()

root.title("Home")
root.geometry("850x550")
root.configure(background='#DEEBF7')
backg = Button(book, height=850, width=550, background='#DEEBF7',
    activebackground='#DEEBF7', border=0)
backg.pack()
#modify the windows size, colour and the size of the grid

logo1 = Button(book, width=175, height=117, border=0, background='#DEEBF7', activebackground='#DEEBF7', command=home_button)
logo = PhotoImage(file='Logo1.gif')
logo1.image = logo
logo1.configure(image=logo)
logo1.place(x=50, y=20)

title = Label(book, text = "GRAHAM'S SCHOOL OF MOTORING", background = '#DEEBF7', font = ("Helvetica 24 bold"))
title.place(x=250, y=40)

frame=Frame(root, width=551, height=384, background='#000000')
frame.place(x=250, y=135)
frame=Frame(root, width=547, height=380, background='#DEEBF7', borderwidth=5)
frame.place(x=252, y=137)

home = Button(book, text = "HOME", height=2, width=20, background='#5F85CD',
    borderwidth=5, activebackground='#A2C7E8', relief='raised', command=home_button)
home.place(x=60, y=150)


bookings = Button(book, text="BOOKINGS", height=2, width=20, background='#5F85CD', borderwidth=5, activebackground='#A2C7E8', relief='raised', command=bookings_button)
bookings.place(x=60, y=235)


student = Button(book, text="STUDENTS", height=2, width=20, background='#5F85CD',
    borderwidth=5, activebackground='#A2C7E8', relief='raised', command=students_button)
student.place(x=60, y=320)


back = Button(book, text="BACK", height=2, width=20, background='#FF5559',
    borderwidth=5, activebackground='#BF230A', relief='raised')
back.place(x=45, y=450)

root.mainloop()
#kick off the window's event-loop
```

Comment: As mentioned  in [python-course.eu Tkinter tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_layout_management.php) you should _never_ mix the `pack`, `grid`, and `place` geometry managers in the same master window.

Comment: Which button? Which frame?

Comment: @PM2Ring: be careful of your terminology. You can combine them in the same window (assuming the window has multiple frames), just not in the same widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok. However, the OP is mixing `.pack` and `place` in the `book` frame.

Answer (score 1):

To put the button on top of the frame, I changed the master widget of the button:

I replaced

```
new_booking = Button(book, text='NEW BOOKING', width=20, height=2, background='#87B7E2')
```

by

```
new_booking = Button(root, text='NEW BOOKING', width=20, height=2, background='#87B7E2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I later spotted this mistake and changed it just as you have but thankyou anyway :)